# Wordpress not use site url when redirect 301

Tags: redirect

I have Wordpress installed in a laravel project.

My Wordpress has site url and home url is same: **https://laravel-domain/column**

I config permalink to **https://laravel-domain/column/sample-post/**

My problem is: when I access link **https://laravel-domain/column/post-name-abc**
Page redirect 301 to **https://laravel-domain/post-name-abc** and **show 404**

My expectation: When access: https://laravel-domain/column/post-name-abc
--> ***Redirect 301 to https://laravel-domain/column/post-name-abc/***

Please help me. thanks

Comment: Are you using a redirect plugin, or are you adding the 301s to your htaccess file?

Comment: @RiaanP I did not use plugin, my project use nginx

Comment: What happens when you add your 301 at the top level domain? does it work then?

Comment: @RiaanP If add your 301 at the top level domain, error multi redirect happen.
I donn't know why permanlink redirect 301 remove ```column``` string in url.
I already config site url and home url is: ```https://laravel-domain/column```

Comment: Hmmm.. Can you not move the Wordpress isntallation to its own folder and simply point a sub domain to it? Having two disparate systems in the same setup can be problematic, especially when dealing with server side stuff.

Comment: @RiaanP  Thanks for your help. Let my try make a subdomain for wordpress.